# how to write simultaneously in a file while the program is still running

Tags: python-2.7

In simple words I have a file which contains duplicate numbers. I want to write unique numbers from the 1st file into a 2nd file. I have opened the 1st file in 'r' mode and the 2nd file in 'a+' mode. But it looks like that nothing is appended in the 2nd file while the program is running which gives wrong output. Any one can help me how do I fix this problem.
Thank you in advance.

This is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fp1 = open('tweet_mention_id.txt','r')


for ids in fp1:
    ids = ids.rstrip()
    ids = int(ids)
    print 'ids= ',ids
    print ids + 1
    fp2 = open('unique_mention_ids.txt','a+')
    for user in fp2:
        user = user.rstrip()
        user = int(user)
        print user + 1
        print 'user= ',user
        if ids != user:
            print 'is unique',ids
            fp2.write(str(ids) + '\n')
            break
        else:
            print 'is already present',ids

    fp2.close()

fp1.close()
```

Comment: Hard to help fix code we can't see.

Comment: I have attached the code. Please go through it

Answer (score 0):

If `unique_mention_ids.txt` is initially empty, then you will never enter your inner loop, and nothing will get written.  You should use the inner loop to determine whether or not the id needs to be added, but then do the addition (if warranted) outside the inner loop.

Similar logic applies for a non-empty file, but for a different reason: when you open it for appending, the file pointer is at the end of the file, and trying to read behaves as if the file were empty.  You can start at the beginning of the file by issuing a `fp2.seek(0)` statement before the inner loop.

Either way: as written, you will write a given id from the first file for *every* entry in the second that it doesn't match, as opposed to it not matching any (which, given the file name, sounds like what you want).  Worse, in the second case above, you will be over writing whatever came after the id that didn't match.

Comment: initially `unique_mention_ids.txt` contains one user id. Well after the program has finished execution, both 1st and 2nd file contain same user ids. When I tried to debug them I found that the inner loop is running only once and so all the user ids in the 1st file are compared  against only the user id that I have written earlier in the 2nd file. While the scenario should be that after writing another user id in 2nd file, next id from 1st file should be compared with both the ids in 2nd file, instead it is compared with only the first id in the 2nd file. You just take a case and run my code.